# Rails route to catch everything except assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to allow admin to create pages on the root path. So far i have:

```
get ':path' => "pages#show" ,:as =>:page, :path => /[^\.]+/
```

Basically i'm trying to ignore all paths with a dot in them (like .png). This does not seem to work as everything is rejected (i only want things in the public directory to be rejected, like fonts, icons, images..)

Thanks

Comment: You can't do that - everything in public is directly rendered by the webserver - it doesn't hit the Rails stack.

Comment: ah ok, so i was looking for trouble where there is none. Good to know, thanks

Comment: @sethvargo, this is not true IF the path to the desired asset does not exist and could cause HUGE problems.Example:your using a js plugin in your rails app, ex. ckeditor, which loads additional scripts from your assets folder. This plugin tries to load a js asset that was not precompiled for whatever reason. Now instead of failing gracefully, it WILL hit your rails stack and it WILL hit your catch-all route. The catch-all should prevent this routing from happening in the first place. My answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By default dynamic segments don’t accept dots – this is because the
>   dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a
>   dot within a dynamic segment add a constraint which overrides this –
>   for example :id => /[^/]+/ allows anything except a slash.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters

So just removing the condition works. There might be another better solution to this problem though.

Answer (score 5):

As I explained in my comment above, "everything in public is directly rendered by the webserver" is NOT true if the desired asset does not exist. This will result in your catch-all route catching this undesired side-effect. This could cause a number of problems, as I explained. So, A specific catch-all route is needed to compensate for this:

```
get ':path' => "pages#show", :as => :page, :constraints => lambda{|req| req.path !~ /\.(png|jpg|js|css)$/ }
```

you can manipulate the regex how ever you see fit as my goal was just to get you on the right track by showing you that you can pass a block to the :constraints option. Also, I didn't just test req.format because that would exclude requests with header information for js format and would result in the catch all not working for these types of requests (not a usual case for a catch-all, but that's irrelevant). By using req.path instead, the header info is left intact/working and the path dictates whether or not this request is caught by this route.

I hope this helps you.

TESTING:
To test to see if your catch-all is actually catching what you want and not additional public resources, follow these steps. First put a debugger in your catch-all action, in your PagesController. Then make a request to a public file png/js/css file that DOES exist, like localhost:3000/images/example_image.png, and it should not hit your catch-all, as usual. Now, change the path to an image that doesn't exist, localhost:3000/images/no_image.png . If the request does not hit your debugger, your catch-all is not catching the image file request, and your ALL SET. If the request does hit your debugger, that means your catch-all is catching the image file request which means you need to revise your constraints in your catch-all.

Comment: you can use `a !~ /b/` instead of `!(a =~ /b/)`

Comment: @trushkevich as much as I like how ruby as a language has abstracted a good majority of basic coding principles into 'one-liners,' with syntactic sugar, I still believe 'readability' trumps shortness.  This `a !~ /b/` is not readable in my mind. Again, this is a personal preference and 1.) does NOT impact the outcome of the code what so ever 2.) does not (in my mind) improve readability, and 3.) does not enforce any good programming principles other than 'hey look! ruby can make things even shorter!'

Comment: @MKrallaProductions.com are you saying that seriously? `!~` is pretty standard in ruby, and what you wrote I can compare to writing `!(a == b)` instead of `a != b`. That's just weird.

Comment: I'm not looking to debate which permutation of that simple line of code is better as I just commmented - a preference is a preference. My original answer was trying to emphasize the point that we are looking for the opposite of the regex. If you really feel that strongly about your preference, you're more than welcome to edit my post :)